# Comparison between MILP and LP solver performance.

Tags: linear-programming

In case of a problem which can be formulated as both MILP or LP, which is more appropriate. Factors into the consideration can be time complexity of solving algorithm, stability and convergence issues and any other as well.

Comment: It is not common a real MIP can be formulated as an LP (ignoring special cases where the integer variables are integer automatically). In general, a MIP takes much more time than an LP (in fact a MIP solver will often solve thousands of LP problems during its execution).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen comparison in terms of numerical stability??

Comment: As a MIP is more complex there are more things that can go wrong. Of course we don't know your models. If the MIP is 2x2 and the LP 1e8 x 1e8 then the MIP model is likely easier to solve.